# Change Sender Name from Verify to My company name in laravel using nexmo

Tags: laravel, notifications, vonage

I try to change the message title provided by nexom "verify" to be my company name. I upgrade my nexmo account and put money in it. I try use from But NOT work.

this my notification

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage;
//use App\admin\Course;

class ConfirmedCourse extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    protected $course;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($course)
    {
     $this->course = $course;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['nexmo'];
    }

 public function toNexmo($notifiable)
    {
      try {
     $message = new NexmoMessage(); 
     $message->from('basma center')->content($this->course)
         ->unicode();
     return $message;
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
    }
 }  
}
```

[image]

How Can I solve this problem please ??
thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the code from Laravel, I believe what you are doing is correct, as it looks like they pass your "from" setting back up the notification stack. The only thing I can think off the top of my head is possibly country restrictions, as different countries have different SMS requirements for the sender data.

You may want to check the [Country Specific Features and Recommendations](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/sections/200622473-Country-Specific-Features-and-Restrictions) list to see if the carrier is overriding this.

Also keep in mind that Laravel Notifications are pure SMS messages, they are not our [Verify](https://developer.nexmo.com/verify/overview) product. You are much more restricted in what you can set as the "from" option with raw SMS (See the country restrictions above).

Comment: yes that's right, I tried other country, and from appear tanks u